# Upper or lower bound of Wasserstein-2 metric on Gaussian distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, metric-spaces, upper-lower-bounds, optimal-transport

I am constructing an iterative algorithm in which the Wasserstein-2 distance metric 
 for continuous Gaussian distributions is being used. I am trying to find a general upper or lower bound of the metric so that an estimation of number of iteration for convergence can be given. Could somebody tell me where to look for?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand; are you searching for bounds on $W_2(G, \mu)$, where $G$ is a Gaussian and $\mu$ is any probability measure with finite second moment? Or are you interested in $W_2(G_1, G_2)$, where $G_1, G_2$ are Gaussians? For the latter the formula can be found on Wikipedia.